# Importing issues with RiTa toolkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependencies, npm-install

I am getting this error when compiling my JS mini script:

`Error: Cannot find module 'rita'`

Which is weird because I installed the `RiTa` dependency in my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "rita": "^1.1.61"
  }
}
```

And the code is really simple:

```
var rita = require('rita');
var rs = rita.RiString("The elephant took a bite!");
console.log(rs.features());
```

Did I forget some dependency? Is there a recent issue with RiTa? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the previous version with `npm i -S rita@1.1.60`.

Answer (score 0):

Current versions work correctly as well (seems there was a problem with v1.1.61)